# Kogito with Quarkus Configure an API Token

Tags: quarkus, kogito

I have a api generated out of a DMN with Kogito and Quarkus. This works good. I find a lot of examples on how to use JWT tokens or basic auth for security (apiKey). But I'm missing how to do a API Token, perhaps as a header that allows me to do basic server-to-server Authentication.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, do you need to add security to your Kogito DMN application using Quarkus? Have you seen this example? https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/tree/main/kogito-quarkus-examples/process-usertasks-with-security-oidc-quarkus

It's not DMN, but it has the configuration you're looking for with Bearer Tokens with backed Auth Server (Keycloak). You might use many flavors of authentication with Keycloak and Quarkus. Kogito it's just yet another Quarkus app.

Comment: @RicardoZanini Thanks, These are the examples that I'm finding. But I don't need an actual auth server (keycloak), this should only be consumed by another micro service, so an fix API token is enough for my use case.

Comment: Take a look: https://quarkus.io/guides/security#authentication-mechanisms